# How to get the name of the element in an array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, visual-studio

I have a data table as part of a step in spec-flow. I want to 'read' the values put into the table and record the value as well as the column/row of the table it was entered in.

I have saved each cell of the table and created a string array with all boxes, and used the following code to check if anything exists in the table:

```
foreach (int value in tableInfo)
{
   if (value > 0)
   {
      int number = value;           
   }
}
```

I have stored the number entered in the table as number, I also want to store the name of the element in the array that contains the number so I can search it against another list and assign the number to that.

Comment: There are very nice lists which would do this for you: Dictionary, KeyedCollection, HashSet, ... And I must admit, that your description did not make things clear for me...

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for a dictionary. A dictionary is essentially a key value pair. The key would be your cell number or cell name, and the value, the value that was in your cell. Let's say that the key is a `string` and the value is an `int`. This is how you will initialize your dictionary:

```
Dictationary<string, int> myDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

Then as you go through that table, you add entries to the dictionary. You can use the add method, or just assign it.

```
myDictionary.Add("MyCellName", 20);
```

or

```
myDictionary["MyCellName"] = 20;
```

Later in your code, if you need to retrieve the value for cell 'xyz', you would just use:

```
var myValue = myDictionary["xyz"];
```

Answer (score 0):

If u have a **DataTable** u can use this loop:

```
foreach (DataRow dtRow in tableInfo.Rows)
{

    foreach(DataColumn dc in tableInfo.Columns)
    {
      var field = dtRow[dc].ToString();
    }
}
```